# Convert coroutine into void

Tags: unity

I want to get rid of a co-routine and do this with a void.

How could I convert his IEnumerator into a void?

```
private IEnumerator pChangeFoV()
{
    float zValue =70f;

    for (float t = 0f; t < FoVDuration; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        float fNew = Mathf.Lerp(_camera.fieldOfView, zValue, t / FoVDuration);
        _camera.fieldOfView = fNew;
        yield return 0;
    }
    _camera.fieldOfView = zValue;
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

```
private void pChangeFoV()
{
    float zValue =70f;

    for (float t = 0f; t < FoVDuration; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        float fNew = Mathf.Lerp(_camera.fieldOfView, zValue, t / FoVDuration);
        _camera.fieldOfView = fNew;
    }
    _camera.fieldOfView = zValue;
}
```

I just removed the **yield** keyword, since it is a special keyword that states that the statement, this case a method, is an iterator (IEnumerator, or T Generic IEnumerator).

Nonetheless, by turning it into void, you are losing the smooth FOV change you wanted to achieve. To turn the functionality into a void, I'd do something like this:

```
private bool smoothChange = true;
private float zValue = 70f;
private float t = 0.0f;

private void Update()
{
    if(smoothChange) pChangeFoV();
}

private void pChangeFoV()
{
    _camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(_camera.fieldOfView, zValue, t);
    t += Time.deltaTime / FoVDuration;

    if(t >= 1.0f)
    {
        _camera.fieldOfView = zValue;
        smoothChange = false;
    }
}
```

Although I'd rather use coroutines for these kinds of functionalities.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't there a typo in your code? You are lerping from "_camera.fieldOfView" to "t". Is that correct?? I don't see how you take the target field-of-view "zValue" into account. If I am wrong, could you perhaps comment your code in order to explain what you're doing?

Comment: Indeed, it was a typo, it is corrected already. Thanks